# PrestaShop Print Features in product list

Tags: php, html, prestashop

I have one problem about printing features in product list:

```
{if isset($product.features)}
    <div class="features">
         {foreach from=$product.features item=feature}
                <table class="feature-pl">
                <tr>
                      <td class="fea-name">{$feature.name}</td>
                      <td class="fea-valu">{$feature.value}</td>
                </tr>
                </table>
          {/foreach}
    </div>
{/if}
```

But I want to print only 2 of those features, so how can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I know its not very *classy* but you can do it like that :

```
{if isset($product.features)}
<div class="features">
     {foreach from=$product.features item=feature}
        {if $feature.name eq "Feature1" or $feature.name eq "Feature2" }
            <table class="feature-pl">
            <tr>
                  <td class="fea-name">{$feature.name}</td>
                  <td class="fea-valu">{$feature.value}</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        {/if}
      {/foreach}
</div>
{/if}
```